# react-graph-vis get access to x,y coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-graph-vis

I want to create a node graph that can be edited. So obviousely I need access to its x,y properties.
How can I set the initial x,y coordinates and also access them as they update?

Other libraries I saw are pretty straight forward, just add the coordinates to the nodes object. However it doesn't seem to work on vis.

```
  "nodes": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Node A",
  "x": 258.3976135253906,
  "y": 331.9783248901367,
  "type": "empty"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Node B",
  "x": 593.9393920898438,
  "y": 260.6060791015625,
  "type": "empty"
},]
```

Comment: add some code you may have tried, or your current code status... the question seems so basic that checking manual should be more than enough... accessing x and y properties should be easy at any point... what difficulties did you face for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what a code sample would help, this isn't a problem that can be solved by common sense or done in 20 different ways. Someone who has experience with this library can say if it can/ cannot be done and share how